# My mapview not shown on play google market

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview, google-play

I developed a MapView app with GPS data. The map works well on my device. But after I released it on Android's Play Store, the app does not show my map. What can I do? Is there another way to display my map? Please help me, this is a very important project for my company.

Comment: have replace your map debug key with the released key you need to key for release app same as debug key

Answer (score 1):

You must get Maps API key **for your Certificate fingerprint:**

I think your are using Maps API key related to current debugging application.

you have created it using this command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\you\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

But you must create it for Signed Application.

**1)** create a key store by right click on project-> Android Tools-> Export Signed Application Package.
Now App's keysrore is generated in path\App.keystore

**2)** create PrivateKeyEntry:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias "your description" -keystore "path\order.keystore" -storepass yourpass -keypass secondpass
```

**3)** get Maps API key for this Certificate fingerprint

**4)** enter it in mapView's apiKey

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:apiKey="********************"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:minHeight="50dip"
            android:minWidth="50dip" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow step by step process from this tutorial.......You will get your answer,

http://www.letsnurture-review.info/technology/how-to-get-google-map-private-key-and-use-it-to-export-an-android-application/

Comment: Server not found on opening the link.

Answer (score -2):

It might be because of the outdated js file.

The following script worked well, give it a try.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```